# PSM kernel matching and bandwith: what observations are used

Tags: kernel-smoothing, propensity-scores, matching

I'm using PSM with an Epanechnikov Kernel and a bandwith of 0.06.

I'm confused about which observations are matched. I thought it was (broadly) like a wheighted radius matching, where every control observation within a 0.06 propensity score distance from treatment unit T1 receives a weight and is matched.

But some sources say all control observations within the common support are matched. I also read that with kernel matching restricting the common support is especially important because all cotnrol units are matched.

So the question is,  with an Epanechnikov Kernel and a bandwith of 0.06 and a treatment unit T1 with a propensity score of 0,5 would a control unit with a score of 0,57 be matched or not?

Comment: Maybe some examples: this ppt. contains formluas for the kernel saying that it only matches within the bandwidth: http://fmwww.bc.edu/RePEc/usug2001/psmatch.pdf  but then again many paper say that with kernel matching all observations are used.